# File is in use when writing to it after creation

Tags: c#, file

So, I'm trying to create a login form, but I need to read and write to files etc, first of all; I'm creating a file then writing 'test' to the file, but if I then delete the file and try and issue my commands at the same time:

```
FileIO.FileCheck("Usernames.pheonix");
FileIO.WriteFile("Usernames.pheonix", "test");
```

It pulls me an error;

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Pheonix Launcher\Pheonix\bin\Debug\Usernames.pheonix' because it is being used by another process.

I can't seem to get me head around why it keeps on doing this, here are my Read/Write file:

```
public static void createFile(String FileName)
{
    File.Create(FileName);
}

public static void WriteFile(String File ,String Message)
{
    FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(File, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs1);
    writer.Write(Message);
    writer.Close();
}

public static void FileCheck(String fileName)
{
    if (File.Exists(fileName))
        Console.WriteLine("File exists.");
    else
        createFile(fileName);
}
```

Comment: is your `createFile` called once, and afterwards you call `WriteFile` for every message you want to log?

Comment: Well I only call it once through FileCheck to see if it's there then call WriteFile. So yes.

Comment: As usr mentions `Dispose` is the keyword here. `FileStream fs1...` should be in a `using` block, as `StreamWriter` should.

Comment: Well, it seems to me that the `createFile` method is redundant. You could do it all in the `WriteFile` method. `CreateOrOpenFile` and add the message to the file. And yes, make sure you put it all in a using block.

Comment: @bas Is it really redundant? Because if you want to use the given overloads this is what you can do since I tought The `FileMode.OpenCreate` is only available in this overload. However I cannot verify and therefore could be wrong :)

Comment: @Silvermind well his current impl creates a file and ignores the returned Stream. So if OP 'only' wants to be sure the file is created, then I'd think FileMode.OpenOrCreate would cover just that. I'm also not sure but it seems that he just wants to append "log string" to a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`File.Create` does create a file - and return an open stream to it. Put it in a `using` block. (Don't just call close on it - that would be a bug because it is not exception safe).

Actually, looking closer I see that you don't need this at all due to `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`. The file will be created anyway.

Comment: Thank you for that, I didn't realize it created the file anywawy. Much appreciated